# How to pass async data to dispatch action so I can use it in action creator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

Redux is harrrrd... At least to me, it is!!! Can someone please explain to me how can I pass this fetched json[0] through mapDispatchToProps to my action creator? And am I doing it right? I am using redux-thunk, is this the correct way of using it?

```js
state = {
    articles: {
      article: []
    }
  };

  qrCodeOnReadHandler = ({ data }) => {
    this.props.onQRRead();
    console.log(this.props.art);
    fetch(data)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json),
          // () => this.props.onQRRead(json[0]),
          this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            articles: {
              ...this.state.articles,
              article: json[0]
            }
          });
      });
  };
```

---

connecting redux

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    art: state.articles.article
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onQRRead: () => dispatch(article())
  };
};
```

---

action creators

```js
export const fetchedArticle = res => {
  return {
    type: ARTICLE,
    res: res
  };
};

export const article = res => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchedArticle(res));
  };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I pass this fetched json[0] through mapDispatchToProps to my
>   action creator

You have to make your `onQRRead` receive an argument like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onQRRead: payload => dispatch(article(payload))
  };
};
```

The name of the function parameter is arbitrary.

For now, you can use it like the way you just did:

```
this.props.onQRRead(json[0])
```

Comment: Hi Nguyễn Thanh Tú, but should i use onQRRead inside of fetch? Because when I use it like that id does not pass the argument, actually it does not dispatch an action. Could you maybe suggest to me where should I use this.props.onQRRead(json[0]) ?

Comment: please provide more information for that additional question :) I mean, please provide your full component implementation

Comment: Actually it works, just like you said, I used this.props.onQRRead(json[0]) inside of fetch, and not () => this.props.onQRRead(json[0]). Now it works just fine. Another question... Can I send more arguments ( json[1],json[2]... ) and if I can, how can i update every property in my state in the reducer when i have only action.payload? Can I do something like action.payload[1], action.payload[2]? Txn in advance

Comment: please make another question :) I'll be there to help for sure